# Doubt about nouns used as adjectives

Tags: grammar, adjectives, nouns

I was reading the following page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microservices

On this page they write both *microservice architecture* and *microservices architecture*.

But also: *microservice-based architecture* and *microservices-based architecture*.

Can anyone explain to me why all these four options are correct and used? The adjective should be neither singular nor plural.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Microservice(s)*  is not an adjective.

It is a noun being used as a modifier. We can do this in English, and they don't become adjcetives.

Words used as modifiers tend to lose their grammatical inflections (cross-linguistically), but this is only a tendency, not a hard rule.

Comment: So *microservice architecture* and *microservices architecture* are the same, and the first option is the most used? (And, in general, all the four options above are correct?)

Comment: I don't know if they're the same or not. Looking for exact meanings (and distinctions of meanings) in phrases like this is usually a waste of time. (They might be used distinctly in precise ways in one publication, but the next publication may use them differently). "Based" in a phrase like this often means mothing at all, but it might mean something in a particular case. The iWeb corpus has "Microservice Architecture": 373; "Microservices A": 592; "M based A": 5; "Ms base A": 3; so your second option seems to be the most common.